# Mysql: Table Name Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, database-design

We are using mysql 5.7 and we want to deploy our application code on premise. Being a dba, I want to encrypt our tables name and nobody can see my tables name (if possible all objects like SP, Function, Triggers, Events).

Is there any work around.

Comment: This is… [very misguided…](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--KoK6pZj4--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/190f4j7jji9bhjpg.jpg) Even if you "encrypt" them, you'll still be able to see the encrypted name. It's now simply a nonsense name. What do you gain by changing the *names* of things?!

Comment: This is interesting requirement from my company. i dont want to share my tables name with client. Infact we are using cloud base product but one big name wants to deploy this product into their own data center. So I dont want to expose my tables name.

Comment: The code interacting with those tables will still need to be able to use those table names. And if the code is running on premise as well, then the client can use that to "decrypt" the names if they really wanted to. So again, if anything, you're just *changing*, a.k.a. *obfuscating* names. How useful is that really?

Comment: hmmm...we also want to use same method to de-encrypt their name on application layer. I was thinking may be someone use the same method but its looking difficult. I dont want to share my table name because same tables are being used on cloud for number of clients.

Comment: And the issue with that is…?

Comment: You need access control, not encryption. If your security hinges on not knowing the table names, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give users a MySQL login.  End of problem.

That is, build an application that interfaces between the user and the database.

Think of any shopping site on the Web -- You don't see database names, table names, or any other detail like that.

(And, no, there is no such encryption feature in 5.7.)

Comment: Not possible to restrict their access on mysql because we are deploying on premise deployment.

Comment: Then you are stuck with the db/table/column GRANTs and VIEWs.  All fo that needs to be hand-written for each case.